# Greatest Value to Lowest Value

Tags: c

Good day, I was practicing about C and encounter a problem. The problem was this part or somewhere here.
`for (ctr = num2; ctr <= num1; ctr++)`
For example the output is

```
Enter the value of n1: 3
Enter the value of n2: 10
4 6 8 10
```

I would like it to start from the greatest `10 8 6 4` instead of the least `4 6 8 10`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, ctr;

    printf("Enter value of n1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("Enter value of n2: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    for (ctr = num2; ctr <= num1; ctr++) {
        if (ctr % 2 == 0)
            printf("%d ", ctr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flip the condition and use subtraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for`, simply replace

```
ctr = num2; ctr <= num1; ctr++
```

with

```
ctr = num1; ctr >= num2; ctr--
```

Your current `for` loop first initializes `ctr` to `num2`. As we go through the loop, `ctr` is incremented such that it's value becomes `num2 + 1`, then `num2 + 2`, ..., then `num1 - 1`, then `num1`. After `ctr` is `num1`, the statement in the loop is executed one last time, then `ctr` is incremented and it's value becomes `num1 + 1`, which exceeds `num1`, causing the loop to end.

- `ctr` takes on the values in `{num2, num2 + 1, ... , num1 - 1, num1, num1 + 1}`. The statement in the loop is executed for each of the values `ctr` takes except for `num1 + 1`.

To reverse this, you initialize `ctr` to `num1` and as we go through the loop, `ctr` should be decremented such that it's value becomes `num1 - 1`, then `num1 - 2`, ..., then `num2`. After `ctr` is `num2`, the statement in the loop is executed one last time, then `ctr` is decremented and it's value becomes `num2 - 1`, which is less than `num2`, causing the loop to end.

- `ctr` takes on the values in `{num1, num1 - 1, ..., num2 + 1, num2, num2 - 1}`. The statement in the loop is executed for each of the values `ctr` takes except for `num2 - 1`.

Notice how in both loops, the statement is executed when `ctr` takes on a value in `{num2, num2 + 1, ..., num1 - 1, num1}`. The only difference is that in the first loop, `ctr` starts with `num2`, moving up to `num1`, whereas in the second loop, `ctr` starts at `num1`, moving down to `num2`.

After making the above change, your program should function as expected. In the code below, I have (1) made the suggested change above and (2) included checks for the return value of `scanf`. It is not necessary to make change (2), but it is typically good practice to check the return value of `scanf`. For reference (from C99 Standard)

> The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
> failure occurs before any conversion. Otherwise, the scanf function
> returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than
> provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

In our case, we expect a `scanf` call of the form `scanf("%d", &num2)` to return `1`. A return value not equal to 1 means there was an error in `scanf`. Currently, our function simply stops the program if there is an error. However, using the `feof` and `ferror` functions, one would be able to know the type of error that occurred and the programmer can choose to make the program behave differently depending on the type of error. For brevity I have omitted the use of `feof` and `ferror` (both from `<stdio.h>`), though I thought I would mention them since we are on the topic of `scanf` errors.

It is also worth noting that you need to be careful that the user does not enter a number for `num2` that is equal to `INT_MIN` (a macro defined in `<limits.h>`), the minimum value for an object of type `int`. While assigning `INT_MIN` to an `int` such as `num2` is not by itself wrong, if `num2` is `INT_MIN`, eventually `ctr` will equal `num2`, the statement in the loop will be executed one "last" time, but then `num2` will be decremented which would mean trying to assign to `num2` a number lower than the minimum value for an object of type `int`. That is, the program will have **undefined behavior**. The likely result of setting `num2` to `INT_MIN` is that the loop will run forever.

**Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    int num1, num2, ctr;

        printf("Enter value of n1: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num2) != 1) {
            printf("scanf: error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Enter value of n2: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num1) != 1) {
            printf("scanf: error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (ctr = num1; ctr >= num2; ctr--)
            if (ctr % 2 == 0)
                printf("%d ", ctr);
        printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Example Session

```
Enter value of n1: 3
Enter value of n2: 10
10 8 6 4
```

Comment: You might add a note regarding this potential problem: if `num2` has a value of `INT_MIN` (`-2147483648` for most systems), the loop has undefined behavior and likely never stops.

Comment: It is a well written answer with special emphasis on ***checking the return*** of `scanf()` and handling the error. As to the comment by @chqrlie you can protect against the problem by `#include <limits.h>` and `if (scanf("%d", &num2) != 1 || num2 == INT_MIN) { fputs ("error: invalid integer value or value out of range.\n", stderr); ... }` Also, no need for `printf()` if there is no conversion specifier in the format string, `puts()` or `fputs()` will do. No need for a string literal in `printf("\n");` when `putchar('\n');` will do. Using `printf()` isn't wrong, just better alternatives.

Comment: Lastly the mixing of prompts for `n1`, but reading `num2` (and vice-versa) effects the readability of the code. Human nature being what it is, its foreseeable that someone reading the code would glance over the `n1`, `num2` connection and start looking for `num1` after the block. Again, not wrong, but more emphasis should be placed on consistent naming and readability.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: instead of making `num2 == INT_MIN` an error, modifying the loop with a proper ending test seems preferable: `if (num2 >= num1) { for (ctr = num2;; ctr--) { if (ctr % 2 == 0) printf("%d ", ctr); if (ctr == num1) break; }}`

Comment: @chqrlie right you are -- again. I knew I should have gone for coffee before typing `:)`

Comment: Using `num2` for number 1 and `num1` for number 2 is really confusing.

Comment: The main reason for `scanf()` to return `0` is failure to convert the input, ie: if the user typed characters that to not start with a number.

Comment: Thanks for the additions plus recommendations @DavidC.Rankin and @chqrlie! I will try to incorporate these into my answer. I completely agree - `num1` should correspond to `n1` and `num2` should correspond to `n2`. Even better would be for `num1` and `num2` to have names that signal to the reader which one is the lower or upper bound. I felt that I would try to change OP's program as little as possible, which is why I did not change the variable names. But I can edit the post to try to include more readable names for any future readers!